# Offer Type for Microsoft Teams App store submission in Microsoft Partner Center?

Tags: microsoft-teams, appsource

We are trying to go through the Microsoft Partner Center steps in preparation of submission of our BlackLine Microsoft Teams App to Microsoft for testing and listing. We are running into issues where the options available in the Partner Center are not matching the documentation provided. What Offer Type should we select if Teams App is not present?

According to the documentation, I should see the following when trying to add a New Offer:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3MIR.png)

But what I am actually seeing is (no option for Teams App):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7T1f.png)

Thank you!

Following provided documentation but it is not matching the Partner Center UI options. Have submitted issue to MicroSoft and re-read the store submission process documentation several times for a remedy. No luck.

Comment: This issue is being tracked here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/1077

Answer (score 0):

I have developed and validated multiple apps now. For it to appear, you need to got to Account Settings and register on the program 'Commercial Marketplace'. Once you are registered, 'Microsoft 365 and Copilot' will appear on your Marketplace. There you can find the Teams App offer :)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsTR.png)